# wkhtmltopdf - libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I'm trying to install wkhtmltopdf on my debian linux server so I will be able to test if it creates a pdf from a url.

I've downloaded wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-i386.tar.bz2 and extracted it's contents to a directory.

When I try to test if it's working, I came across the next error:

> /usr/local/bin# wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
>   wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I'm trying to install https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle on my symfony2 and I think I need to install wkhtmltopdf on my linux first. Am I right?

Comment: I struggled with the same thing, so first run this (change path according to your case) to see what is missing:
ldd /vagrant/htdocs/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
And then Install the missing stuff:
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1 libxrender1

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It took me a few hours to solve this one, but you need to install libfontconfig1 also e.g.:

```
apt-get install libfontconfig1
```

Comment: libfontconfig1 is already the newest version

Comment: @Alon: it is not installed by default, at least on my systems it was not.

Comment: That what the apt-get install libfontconfig1 returned. I'm running debian

Comment: in Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't work, also installed libfontconfig1-dev and getting the same result

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu 13.10 (maybe others) and on x86 system, this will install x64 library. Use `apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386` instead

Comment: FYI, For Ubuntu 14.04, `apt-get install libxrender-dev`