# FreeBSD linux library installation

Tags: linux, phantomjs, shared-libraries, freebsd

I'm new to FreeBSD. I want to run phantomjs on it. I've run linux emulation according to [FreeBSD Linux® Binary Compatibility](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu-lbc-install.html)  I manually installed 32bit phantom in accordance to this answer [phantom instalation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778513/how-can-i-setup-run-phantomjs-on-ubuntu). After all that steps, when I'm trying to run command `phantomjs -v` I'm getting an error like this

`phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I can't figure out, how shoud I install libfontconfig.so.1 library on FreeBSD to make it works. Thanks for all suggestion!

Comment: Can you refer this - https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10904 Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @SomanDubey , thank for response! I tried to run this command `pkg install phantomjs`, but I got this `pkg: No packages available to install matching 'phantomjs' have been found in the repositories
`.

Comment: I was referring to this post - It is solved for my by running sudo apt-get install libfontconfig on that environment.
Thanks to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046555/wkhtmltopdf-libfontconfig-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file in above link

Comment: try following sof link above

Comment: @SomanDubey unfortunately, I can't run this command because I have only possibility to run linux binaries in freebsd environment. It should be `pkg install phantomjs` command alternative to `apt-get install libfontconfig`, but it doesn't work (my comment above)

Comment: I haven't worked in freebsd environment. but as far as my knowledge goes, you will have to figure out a way to install libfontconfig. I'm sorry but this is far I can go.

Comment: @SomanDubey, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g@crayon2:/usr/local/lib % pkg which /usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 was installed by package fontconfig-2.11.1_1,1
```

You should be able to install that library with:

```
pkg install x11-fonts/fontconfig
```

Then it should be placed in the `/usr/local/lib` folder (as in the example above).