# Rails 4 - wkhtmltopdf command failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

When i try to run wkhtmltopdf (`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf - test.pdf`) directly, i got the following error

`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

`sudo apt-get install libfontconfig` not working for me.

Is any configuration for this, please guide me to proceed further, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wkhtmltopdf - libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046555/wkhtmltopdf-libfontconfig-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

Comment: try `apt-get install libfontconfig1`

Answer (score 0):

please try running following command on ubuntu

`try apt-get install libfontconfig1`