# Docker and Spatie PdfToText error exit code: 127

Tags: php, linux, docker, ubuntu

I have this code:

```
Global $windows;

$libiary_path = "./pdftotext";
if($windows)
{
    $libiary_path .= ".exe";
}

$text = (new Pdf($libiary_path))->setPdf($file_name)->text();
return $text;
```

On linux in VM it works. I switched an docker and I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Spatie\PdfToText\Exceptions\CouldNotExtractText: The command "'./pdftotext' 'this.pdf' '-'" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) Working directory: /var/www/html Output: ================ Error Output: ================ ./pdftotext: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/pdf-to-text-main/src/Pdf.php:73 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/get_data.php(18): Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf->text() #1 /var/www/html/get_data.php(59): parsePDF('this.pdf') #2 /var/www/html/get_data.php(69): GetDataFromPDF('this.pdf') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/pdf-to-text-main/src/Pdf.php on line 73
```

[image]

Everything is there. Exactly the same set of files on the Ubuntu VM and lampp works, not on the Ubuntu docker. I'm a beginner and maybe I don't understand something, but I can't find the answer on the web. Perhaps this is some very basic mistake.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Can you post your Dockerfile for building the container? 2) I see there's an error about `libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file`. Have you tried installing libfontconfig inside the container?

Comment: I have yes, but it does not matter, because I am now rummaging in the system on the docker to develop a more correct Dockerfile. I suspect that it is missing chmod and just something to fix this error, and how to install this library in the docker? https://pastebin.com/AHvdM8Mx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046555/wkhtmltopdf-libfontconfig-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file - próbowalem tego - nie pomogło.