# Phantomjs won't install: Autoconfiguration Error

Tags: phantomjs

When trying to install Phantomjs on Ubuntu 22.04, I get the following error:
There are some Q.& A's here from 2015-2022, I tried all of the included suggestions.

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10904

https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620

[wkhtmltopdf - libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046555/wkhtmltopdf-libfontconfig-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

http://ubuntuhowtoo.blogspot.com/2019/05/linux-nodejs-phantomjs-error-loading.html

````
Auto configuration failed
139998593603520:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libproviders.so): libproviders.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
139998593603520:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
139998593603520:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=providers, path=providers
139998593603520:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=providers```
````

Answer (score 41):

I had the same issue and fixed it by setting `export OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null` prior to phantomJS usage. If it's not possible for you to disable openssl then you would have to pack you application with older OpenSSL version.

Explanation:
Ubuntu 22.04 uses the new OpenSSL version 3.0.2 instead of the older OpenSSL version 1.1.1 . These OpenSSL versions are not fully compatible, so this is why you see this error when PhantomJS tries to auto configure the SSL/TLS settings.

Comment: does this change impact the functionality of phantom ?  I would think so

Comment: I'm using PhantomJS for headless unit tests of client-side code and it's totally fine, so if your use case is similar then I'm sure it'll be okay.

Comment: Works for me for making a PDF via decktape. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is little about as I am describing.

Step:1 First stop your node server then run this command in base directory.

Step:2 I suggest you to comment out the lines providers = provider_sectin in the
file/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

Step:3 Start your application

**Brief ref**. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43132